# Visualizar una fecha

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de visualizar un campo tipo fecha y aunque cuando uso el `print` la veo no se muestra en el `entry`, 
Que estoy haciendo mal? acá le dejos varias partes del código:

Aquí hago la consulta

```
for BBDDEscuela in elUsuario:
    miID.set(BBDDEscuela[0])
    miNombre1.set(BBDDEscuela[1])
    miNombre2.set(BBDDEscuela[2])
    miApellido1.set(BBDDEscuela[3])
    miApellido2.set(BBDDEscuela[4])
    miSexo.set(BBDDEscuela[5])
    miFecha=(BBDDEscuela[6])
    miDias.set(BBDDEscuela[7])
miConexion.commit()
```

Aquí tengo el `Entry`, me lo muestra en el `print` pero no en el cuadro del `Entry`

```
cuadroFecha=Entry(miFrame1, textvariable=miFecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
cuadroFecha.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10)
print(miFecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer `entry.insert(0, "Tu texto")` para escribir tu String en la ventana. Vale aclarar que el metodo `insert()` toma como primer argumento una posición y como segundo la cadena que le quieras pasar, en este caso tu fecha.

Por otro lado para dibujar una variable, como creo que necesitas en este caso, puedes utilizar con Tkinter

```
entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
```

[Mas informacion](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/caja-de-texto-entry-tkinter/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, he utilizado el método 'insert()'  y me da error, yo quiero dibujar la fecha que tengo en la base de datos, logro consultar pero cuando trato de fijarla en pantalla, simplemente no aparece. No entiendo porque si hago un ´print´ aparece la fecha en la consola pero no en pantalla.

Comment: Que error especifico te da? Probaste con el segundo metodo que agregue? Saludos.

Comment: cuadroFecha=entry.insert(0, miFecha)       Inserte esta linea y me aparece el siguiente error

Comment: __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Escuela.py", line 164, in creador
    cuadroFecha=entry.insert(0, miFecha)
NameError: name 'entry' is not defined

Comment: No tienes entry definido, mira el link que adjunte en mi respuesta para ver si entiendes mejor el concepto.  Prueba con `cuadroFecha.insert(0, "Tu texto")`